# How can I test if an object is an angular scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I was trying to create a small abstraction layer on top of UI-Booststrap [modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) to remove duplicate code with a factory that allows you to call modals it like this

```
modal.dialog({
    templateUrl: <String>
    scope: <Scope>
}). then(...);
```

I set validation in my factory like this

```
if (settings && angular.isString(settings.templateUrl) ...)
```

but when I tried to validate the `<Scope>` part I run out of luck. I couldn't find an `angular.isScope` function.

How can I test for this?

I'm aware that with a decent amount of work any object might look like a `$scope` object and if you are paranoid and try add more validation rules is like going down the rabbit hole, you will end up lost, so please dont do that. What I want is an easy way that can detect a decent number of false values to set up my validation.

Answer (score 4):

I started looking at the angular code. I found an [isScope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L634) function that does this

```
function isScope(obj) {
    return obj && obj.$evalAsync && obj.$watch;
}
```

Basically [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) to check if the object resembles an angular scope. This is simple enough and can be used for most cases but I wanted to know if there was a better way, more reliable than

```
isScope({$watch:true ,$evalAsync:true})    => true
```

I found out that every scope object contains a `$root` property that point to the `$rootScope`. This is valid even for the `$rootScope` itself.

```
$rootScope.$root === $rootScope            => true
```

So this is still duck-typing but is a little better than the previous one because we are using [identity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) to check if the objects are exactly the same. Moving this into a usable factory

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('isScope', function($rootScope) {
    return function(obj) {
      return obj && obj.$watch && obj.$evalAsync && obj.$root === $rootScope;
    };
  });
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('isScope', function($rootScope) {
    return function(obj) {
      return obj && obj.$watch && obj.$evalAsync && obj.$root === $rootScope;
    };
  })
  .controller('TestController', function($scope, isScope) {
    $scope.resultObject = isScope({
      $watch: true,
      $evalAsync: true
    });
    $scope.resultScope = isScope($scope);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController">
  <div>Object: {{resultObject}}</div>
  <div>Scope: {{resultScope}}</div>
</div>
```

Of course this can be easily fooled using `{..., $root: $rootScope}` but it will be better when testing simple objects.

Still, I keep looking and reading the source code and found that all scopes are created using a function statement named [Scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L167)(obviously :P). Of course this function is private and not exposed to the outside world, or is it!!???

Imagine my surprise when I was looking and I found it

[image: Scope angular function]

This is of course useless to create new scopes, there is an api function for that [`$rootScope.$new`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) but could be used to test for scopes using the prototype chain.

Ok but wait, I know that isolated scopes do not prototypically inherit from other scopes so the chain will be broken. Turns out that for those cases angular uses [`new Scope()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L241) to instantiate a brand new isolate scope so this trick might still work and it will be better than the previous attempts.

```
function isScope(obj) {
    var Scope = $rootScope.constructor;
    return obj instanceof Scope;
}
```

This will detect our previous attempt

```
console.log(isScope({..., $root: $rootScope}));    => false
```

Moving this to a usable factory

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .factory('isScope', function($rootScope) {
        return function(obj) {
            return obj instanceof $rootScope.constructor;
        };
    });
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('isScope', function($rootScope) {
    return function(obj) {
      return obj instanceof $rootScope.constructor;
    };
  })
  .controller('TestController', function($rootScope, $scope, isScope) {
    $scope.objectResult = isScope({
      $evalAsync: true,
      $watch: true,
      $root: $rootScope
    });
    $scope.scopeResult = isScope($scope);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController">
  <div>
    Object: {{objectResult}}
  </div>
  <div>
    Scope: {{scopeResult}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Like I said, this is not fail proof, in fact is very easy to fool using something like

```
function FakeScope() { }
FakeScope.prototype = $rootScope;
var fakeInstance = new FakeScope();

console.log(isScope(fakeInstance))     => true
```

but is good enough for testing most real use cases. Of course like every use of [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) there are undesired side effects when using in multiple contexts(e.g. frames or windows) and this will also return false for real scope objects in a different frame but this is an extreme case that is very unlikely to occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the object is an instance of the $scope. This isnt perfect but it might suffice.

```
if(scope instanceof $scope.constructor){ 
    /* enter code here */
}
```

Comment: This is the same that I wrote on my answer. The reason I use `$rootScope` instead is because this is the only scope that is always available. Imagine you are testing this in a run block, there is no scope there so this method is useless in this case.